# Compare each row in sheet1 to each row in sheet2 -no pair write in sheet3 - HARD

Tags: vba, comparison, compare, rows

I have an very big Excel file that has exactly same columns but dirosa. ent many rows. I need help with an VBA-script to compare each entire Eos in sheet1 with sheet2 If it dont finds an pair I want it to write the row in sheet3.
Its very important that the script starts in row 1 in sheet1 and then loop true whole Range in sheet2 to check If it fond an pair or not. If it cant find an match then I want it to write that row in sheet3.

Please need all help I can get!!

Using Excel 2010 - VBA script pls

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with loops. If there are a lot of rows in your columns, this may take a lot of time. Otherwise it works fine. Basically the codes takes every value from sheet1, compares it to every value of sheet2 and writes it in sheet3 if no match was found. Then it repeats the same thing but comparing sheet2 values to sheet1 values.

```
Sub Compare()

'Get Lengths of the Columns
Z_1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Z_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Variable row index for Sheet3
a = 1

'Find exclusive values in sheet1
For i = 1 To Z_1
    j = 1
    Do Until ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1) Or j > Z_2
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) <> ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(a, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next i

'Find exclusive values in sheet2
For i = 1 To Z_2
    j = 1
    Do Until ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1) Or j > Z_1
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) <> ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1) Then
         ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(a, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1)
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Its not working - Its only compare column A and not the entire row. How can this be solved? Its important that the script compare entire rows.